# Understanding Swift 2.2 Selector Syntax - #selector()

Tags: swift, swift2, selector

I am switching over the syntax of my project toward Swift 2.2 (which xCode helps me do automatically); however, I do not understand the new `#selector()` syntax.

As an example:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, 
             selector: #selector(MyVC.timerCalled(_:)), //new selector syntax!
             userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This has the selector `#selector(MyVC.timerCalled(_:))`

What does the `_:` signify? Can you add other variables into this selector? Say, `#MyVC.timerCalled(_:whateverVar)`.

General info on what is different in this syntax as opposed to the string based implementation from earlier versions of Swift are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I explain it nicely here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax/35658335#35658335

Comment: @matt’s Answer addresses the syntax more thoroughly, including a useful discussion of dealing with overloaded methods.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The bit in parenthesis is a mechanism for identifying the argument list for the selector that you want.

I recommend you look at the [Generalized Naming](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0021-generalized-naming.md) proposal from Swift Evolution.  It covers cases where you have a number of functions that differ only by their parameter labels and need to refer to them.  The example from that document is:

```
extension UIView {
  func insertSubview(view: UIView, at index: Int)
  func insertSubview(view: UIView, aboveSubview siblingSubview: UIView)
  func insertSubview(view: UIView, belowSubview siblingSubview: UIView)
}
```

If you wanted to get a function value for one of those the result is ambiguous:

```
let fn = someView.insertSubview // ambiguous: could be any of the three methods
```

The solution implemented is to add the argument labels, without any type information to the code that generates the function value to disambiguate which you want:

```
let fn = someView.insertSubview(_:at:)
let fn1 = someView.insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)
```

See how the labels are added in the parens?

This proposal played a role in the one that most directly applies to your question:

[Referencing the Objective-C selector of a method](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md)

In this particular case the selector you want to refer to is `timerCalled:` which is a function of one parameter that has no label.  Hence (_:).  The underscore means the label is not specified and the colon.

Answer (score 19):

Swift 2.2 has deprecated Stringified selectors: In swift 2.0, we use to write the selector as a String i.e `"buttonClicked"`. The disadvantage with this approach is that the compiler can't check whether the method really exists or not at compile time(Even if you have misspelled it).

**EX:1**

```
func buttonClicked(){
}
```

So the above method in the new approach can be called as `#selector(buttonClicked)`

**EX:2**

```
func buttonClicked(stringValue : String){
}
```

So the above method in the new approach can be called as `#selector(buttonClicked(_:))`

**EX:3**

```
func buttonClicked(stringValue : String, indexValue : Int){
}
```

So the above method with parameters in the new approach can be called as `#selector(buttonClicked(_:indexValue:))`

Comment: Hey, I have just been reading this question. Could you please briefly explain to me why the compiler would fix/change your above example to #selector(YourClass.buttonClicked) instead of just #selector(buttonClicked) when converting to swift 2.2. Is there a difference between the 2? Thank you

Comment: @crashoverride777 i think your question was explained clearly here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: I think you always need to prefix the method declaration with @objc

Answer (score 9):

Consider below code for adding target to button in swift 3 using #selector

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(sender:)),
                       for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

 func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!){

 }
```

This syntax worked for me when migrating to swift 3

Answer (score 8):

This is the way Swift method signatures are represented in documentation, and it is now beginning to be used in new language features such as the `#selector()` syntax to express methods by their argument lists.

The each colon (`:`) represents a method parameter. For named parameters, the colon is preceded by the external parameter name; for unnamed parameters, an underscore (`_`) is used.

So for example, `MyVC.timerCalled(_:))` indicates a method on the `MyVC` type with one unnamed parameter, which might be declared like this:

```
func timerCalled(timer: NSTimer) { ... }
```

(Note that `timer` is the *internal* parameter name, since by default the first parameter of a method is unnamed)

The type (`MyVC` in your example) can also be omitted if it is within the same scope of the `#selector()` declaration.

A more complex example might look like this:

```
let sel = #selector(aMethodWithSeveralParameters(_:secondParam:thirdParam:))

...

func aMethodWithSeveralParameters(firstParam: Int, secondParam: Int, thirdParam: Int) { ... }
```