# swift 2.2 #selector on var

Tags: swift, swift2

I use Typhoon and I need selector for injection property

```
definition.injectProperty(Selector("viewModel"), with: self.viewModel.inviteViewModel())
```

but compiler don't see selector define as var.

for example:
if I have `var viewModel: AuthViewModel!` and

use `#selector(viewModel)`

so I get `Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to a property`

UPDATE:

I have the problem from used Typhoon in Swift. I resolve my problem like renouncement from Typhoon and switch to Swinject.
Also now I can use struct for injection and much more.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36166248/2227743

Comment: selector on func it work. But selector on var don't see

Comment: please, add a minimum example.

Comment: Also see "Selector availability" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/2227743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of what can be passed into `#selector()`. You should definitely read the StackOverflow questions that Eric D posted:

Overview on what you can use `#selector()` for: [Understanding Swift 2.2 Selector Syntax - #selector()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36166248/2227743)

The reason why you can not pass a Swift property in to `#selector()`:

> Selector availability: The method referenced by the selector must be
>   exposed to the ObjC runtime. This is already the case if it's in a
>   class that (ultimately) inherits from NSObject, but if it's in a pure
>   Swift class you'll need to preface that method's declaration with
>   @objc. Remember that private symbols aren't exposed to the runtime,
>   too — your method needs to have at least internal visibility.

*- Referenced from [@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift/24007718#24007718)*

In short, you can't pass in a `var` and you need to pass a function that the Objective-C runtime is aware of. Either it is an Objective-C method, or  it is a Swift method marked as `@objc`.

Comment: AuthViewModel subclass from NSObject and class used viewModel also subclass UIViewController. What can I do? If I use Selector("viewModel") it work but I have warning. But I can't use #selector because viewModel is "var"?