# Swift 2.2 string literal selector

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, uilocalizedcollation

Before the update I this code worked fine:

```
var alphabetizedArray = [[Person]]()

    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation()

    for person : Person in ContactsManager.sharedManager.contactList {
        var index = 0
        if ContactsManager.sharedManager.sortOrder == .FamilyName {
            index = collation.sectionForObject(person, collationStringSelector: "lastName")
        }
        else {
            index = collation.sectionForObject(person, collationStringSelector: "firstName")
        }
        alphabetizedArray.addObject(person, toSubarrayAtIndex: index)
    }
```

But now since string literal selectors are no longer alowed the code broke.

I tried to change string literal selector to Selector("lastName"), but the 'index' is always returned as -1. And I don't see any solution.

This collation method takes a property name of the given object. And Person class is really have those properties (lastName, firstName).

But how can I get this work again? Experiments with #selector gave me nothing: 'Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an initializer or method' it says. No wonder since this sectionForObject(, collationStringSelector:) takes no methods but a property names.

Comment: matt's one is also a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35658335/2227743

Comment: I've seen that, but I don't see how it helps in my case. In my case I need no method as selector, but a property name for some kind of sorting. And no matter with what syntax I write this selector, that isn't working because the new syntax requires existing method names and not string literals.

Comment: But [sectionForObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILocalizedIndexedCollation/sectionForObject:collationStringSelector:) takes a selector which "identifies a method returning an identifying string for object that is used in collation" so using Module.Class.method should work (maybe in your class you have to have a method returning the property instead of just trying to use the property with the new syntax? Not sure about that.)

Comment: I wrote a test func in my Person class 
 class func lastNameString() -> String {
  return "lastName"
 }
And I changed selector to this #selector(Person.lastNameString).
But now I have crash with error unrecognized selector sent to instance. It's a mystery.

Comment: Did you try Module.Class.method instead of just Class.method? Just a guess. Some mysteries indeed. If you actually can't find a solution for this specific question I'll re-open it.

Comment: Believe me, I'm searching through google and stackoverflow for 2 days. And nothing. P.S.: Module.Class.method didn't change anything

Comment: I've reopened the question.

Comment: this is example you are using http://kostiakoval.github.io/posts/swift-and-ios-sdk/?

Comment: Oleg Gordiichuk, like I said in my question, that code isn't working in Swift 2.2.

Comment: Eric D. thanks for reopening! Martin R finally got the solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a combination of several problems:

- The collation must be created with `UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation()`.
- The object class needs an *instance method* returning a `String`.
- The `#selector` must refer to that instance method, both `#selector(<Type>.<method>)` and `#selector(<instance>.<method>)` can be used.

Here is a self-contained example which seems to work as expected:

```
class Person : NSObject {
    let firstName : String
    let lastName : String

    init(firstName : String, lastName : String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    func lastNameMethod() -> String {
        return lastName
    }
}
```

and then

```
let person = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation()
let section = collation.sectionForObject(person, collationStringSelector: #selector(Person.lastNameMethod))
print(section) // 3
```

Here, both `#selector(Person.lastNameMethod)` and `#selector(person.lastNameMethod)` can be used.

Comment: Nice touch! Thanks a lot! But I still think that Apple has turned the wrong way in Swift development with this #selector mess.

Answer (score 0):

For solving of your issue at first read new documentation about Selectors in Swift2.2.

Example: Use `#selector(CLASS.lastName)` instead of `Selector("lastName")`. Where CLASS it is actual class that contains this method.

Comment: I've tried that too. And all I get is this: Instance member 'lastName' cannot be used on type 'Person'.