# Xcode 7.3, Swift 2.2: default initialiser selector (new compile-time check)

Tags: swift

I'm migrating some selectors to Swift 2.2 but I'm having an issue with one of them:

[image: Init string selector]

*Code:*

```
let hook = ARTRealtimePresenceQuery.testSuite_injectIntoClassMethod("init") { // Default initialiser
    presenceQueryWasCreated = true
}
```

Now, Xcode want to help me doing the transition but in a wrong way:

[image]

*Code:*

```
let hook = ARTRealtimePresenceQuery.testSuite_injectIntoClassMethod(#selector(_NSEnumeratorType.init)) { // Default initialiser
    presenceQueryWasCreated = true
}
```

I try to fix it:

[image]

*Code:*

```
let hook = ARTRealtimePresenceQuery.testSuite_injectIntoClassMethod(#selector(ARTRealtimePresenceQuery.init)) { // Default initialiser
    presenceQueryWasCreated = true
}
```

So, my question is: How can I select the default initialiser method with the new `#selector` syntax?

(It was working in Swift 2.0.)

**Current error**:

"*Ambiguous use of 'init()'*"

**UPDATE 1:**

`ARTRealtimePresenceQuery` initialisers:

```
- (instancetype)init;
- (instancetype)initWithClientId:(nullable NSString *)clientId connectionId:(nullable NSString *)connectionId;
- (instancetype)initWithLimit:(NSUInteger)limit clientId:(nullable NSString *)clientId connectionId:(nullable NSString *)connectionId;
```

Comment: I am not familiar with that framework, what does `testSuite_injectIntoClassMethod` do, and the init method of which class do you want to refer to? – Note that `Selector("init")` is still valid!

Comment: @MartinR The `testSuite_injectIntoClassMethod` adds a block of code after the current `selector` for a specific class. In this case, I want to add a block of code in the default initialiser of `ARTRealtimePresenceQuery`. Can I still use the `Selector("init")` without a warning? I think not.

Comment: Can you try `#selector(ARTRealtimePresenceQuery.init as () -> ARTRealtimePresenceQuery)` ? It should compile without warning, but don't know if it works as intended.

Comment: @MartinR It works! Great, really thank you. Please write an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As demonstrated in

- [How do I resolve "ambiguous use of" compile error with Swift #selector syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax),

referring to the no-parameter variant as one of several overloaded
methods requires an explicit `as <signature>` cast.
That method can be applied to init methods as well:

```
class MyClass : NSObject {

    override init() { }

    init(s : String) { }
}

// Selector referring to init():
let sel1 = #selector(MyClass.init as () -> MyClass)

// Selector referring to init(s : String):
let sel2 = #selector(MyClass.init as (String) -> MyClass)
```

So in your case it would be

```
#selector(ARTRealtimePresenceQuery.init as () -> ARTRealtimePresenceQuery)
```