# Swift Error : UITableViewController has no member "function name"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to open a date picker within a text field.
The following error is being displayed.

[image: Code]

Code as follows:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class tableview : UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {

    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()        
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date        
    sender.inputView = datePickerView        
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UITableViewController.datePickerValueChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}
func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()        
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle        
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle        
    dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    **strong text**
}
```

Comment: The answer is probably here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax/35658335#35658335

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make proper name to class tableview.(tableview -> TableViewController).

For add target you have to write class nmae.so here is class name  (tableview -> TableViewController)

If you are using IBOutlet for textfield then put inputView code in viewDidLoad.

Try below code.

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    class TableViewController : UITableViewController {

       @IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!

       func viewDidLoad(){

           super.viewDidLoad()
           let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

           datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

           dateTextField.inputView = datePickerView

           datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.datePickerValueChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

    @IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {


    }
    func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

        dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
        **strong text**
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
 datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

You are missing param of that function.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerValueChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

or

```
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```