# How to discriminate same method selector on Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, selector, swift3

I found two methods in `UITextViewDelegate` that available in iOS 10 or newer.

I seem them has difference type of second parameter (URL or NSTextAttachment).

```
optional func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool

optional func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool
```

When I use selector:

```
#selector(self.textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)
```

These two method has same syntax to defined a selector, so, how to discriminate them and how to fix error `Ambiguous use of 'textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)'` ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you have written code just convert it in to swift 3.0 code using editor -> convert

Comment: Already converted to swift 3.0, but build error yet. >_<

Comment: You simply have to cast the methods to disambiguate (e.g `#selector(self.textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:) as (UITextView, URL, NSRange, UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool)`), see for example [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax) on how to resolve selector ambiguities.

Comment: @Hamish Good solved! Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in Swift 5