# How to access camera with swiping gesture?

Tags: swift, camera, gesture

I have added a swipe gesture in my ios application, but somehow I can't access the camera afterward. I am beginner in swift and I would be very glad if you can advice me how to fix it.
So far I have used:

```
  import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{

 let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()
 let reachability = Reachability()!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatBlackColorDark()

    let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("handleSwipes")))

    upSwipe.direction = .up

    view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)

}
```

and for the function:

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if (sender.direction == .up){

            if ( UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)){
                if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil {
                    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
                    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
                    present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: {})
                }
            }
```

Comment: What happens when you swipe? Did you debug? Is `handleSwipes` even called?

Comment: This is the error I get: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Audio.ViewController handleSwipes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100d0be50'

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be what was happening! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have:

```
action: Selector(("handleSwipes"))
```

put this:

```
action: #selector(handleSwipes)
```

The reason is that `"handleSwipes"` is *not* the selector for your `handleSwipes` function, and *you* do not know how to form the selector correctly. But the compiler does know, and using `#selector` syntax tells it to do so.

Comment: Actually it needs to be `handleSwipes(sender:)`, not just `handleSwipes`.

Comment: @rmaddy No it doesn't.

Comment: Why not? The actual method takes a parameter so the selector needs to include the parameter.

Comment: @rmaddy No it doesn't. The bare name is sufficient provided there is no ambiguity. And there is no ambiguity. See my discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35658335/341994 where I explain the syntax for you.

Comment: Thanks. That's a subtlety of Swift I didn't know.

Comment: @rmaddy I know you didn't. :) I much prefer the "bare name" syntax; it saves a mess of typing.

Comment: Thanks also, @matt. I've wondered why both ways of #selector works - seems odd given how much work has gone into making Swift "safe". Given you an up vote for that.