# No build errors but crashes in simulator.

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, xcode8.2

I get no build errors but once I am in the simulator and press the + in the top right corner to add new url the program crashes. This is the error I get:

> 2017-02-21 09:37:48.667 Favorite Websites[2211:128142] ->[Favorite_Websites.MasterViewController addButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff266408aa0
>   2017-02-21 09:37:48.672 Favorite Websites[2211:128142] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Favorite_Websites.MasterViewController addButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff266408aa0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d0b0d4b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cb1221e objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d120f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d036005 ___forwarding_** + 1013
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d035b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000010d4d68bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010d9184a1 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 149
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010d4d68bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010d65cc38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010d65cf51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010d65d0db -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 838
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010d65be4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010d544545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010d545c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
>       14  UIKit                               0x000000010d4f29ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010dcdf72d **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
>       16  UIKit                               0x000000010dcd8463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d055761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d03a98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d039e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d039884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>       21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011173fa6f GSEventRunModal + 161
>       22  UIKit                               0x000000010d4d4c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       23  Favorite Websites                   0x000000010c516e0f main + 111
>       24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001107af68d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Here is the MasterViewController.swift code where the error comes from.

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, ModelDelegate {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil


    var model: Model! = nil // manages the app's data

    // conform to ModelDelegate protocol; updates view wehn model changes
    func modelDataChanged(){
        tableView.reloadData() // reload the UITableView
    }

    // called after the view loads for further UI configuration
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set up left and right UIBarButtonItems
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: Selector(("addButtonPressed:")))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }

        model = Model(delegate: self) // create the Model
        model.synchronize() // tell model to sync its data

    }

    // displays a UIAlertController to obtain new url from user

    func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        displayAddEditurlSearchAlert(isNew: true, index: nil)
    }

    // handles long press for editing or sharing a url
    func tableViewCellLongPressed(
        sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began &&
            !tableView.isEditing {
            let cell = sender.view as! UITableViewCell // get cell

            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
                displayLongPressOptions(row: indexPath.row)
            }
        }
    }

    // displays the edit/share options
    func displayLongPressOptions(row: Int){
        // create UIAlertController for user input
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Options",
                                                message: "Edit or Share your url",
                                                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // create Cancel action
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                         style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit",
                                       style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
                                       handler: {(action) in
                                        self.displayAddEditurlSearchAlert(isNew: false, index: row)})
        alertController.addAction(editAction)

        let shareAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share",
                                        style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
                                        handler: {(action) in self.shareurlSearch(index: row)})
        alertController.addAction(shareAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true,
                              completion: nil)
    }

    // displays add/edit dialog
    func displayAddEditurlSearchAlert(isNew: Bool, index: Int?){
        // create UIAlertController for user input
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: isNew ? "Add URL" : "Edit URL",
            message: isNew ? "" : "Modify your URL",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // create UITextFields in which user can enter a new URL
        alertController.addTextField(
            configurationHandler: {(textField) in
                if isNew {
                    textField.placeholder = "Enter URL"
                }else{
                    textField.text = self.model.queryForTagAtIndex(index: index!)
                }
        })

        alertController.addTextField(
            configurationHandler: {(textField) in
                if isNew {
                    textField.placeholder = "Tag your URL"
                }else {
                    textField.text = self.model.tagAtIndex(index: index!)
                    textField.isEnabled = false
                    textField.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
                }
        })

        // create Cancel action
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                         style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
                                       style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
                                       handler: {(action) in
                                        let query =
                                            ((alertController.textFields?[0])! as UITextField).text
                                        let tag =
                                            ((alertController.textFields?[1])! as UITextField).text

                                        // ensure query and tag are not empty
                                        if !query!.isEmpty && !tag!.isEmpty {
                                            self.model.saveQuery(
                                                query: query!, forTag: tag!, syncToCloud: true)

                                            if isNew {
                                                let indexPath =
                                                IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                                                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath],
                                                                          with: .automatic)
                                            }
                                        }
        })
        alertController.addAction(saveAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true,
                              completion: nil)

    }

    // displays share sheet
    func shareurlSearch(index: Int) {
        let message = "Check out this cool Web site"
        let urlString = urlEncodeString(string: model.queryForTagAtIndex(index: index)!)
        let itemsToShare = [message, urlString]

        // create UIActivityViewController so user can share url
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: itemsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityViewController,
                              animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

        // MARK: - Segues


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

                // get query String
                let query = String(model.queryForTagAtIndex(index: indexPath.row)!)

                // create NSURL to perfrom url search

                controller.detailItem = NSURL(string: urlEncodeString(string: query!))
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // returns a URL encoded version of the query String
    func urlEncodeString(string: String) -> String {
        return string.addingPercentEncoding(
            withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
    }

    // MARK: - Table View
    // callback that returns total number of sections in UITableView
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // callback that returns number of rows in the UITableView
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }

    // callback that returns a configured cell for the given NSIndexPath
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // get cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        // set up long press guesture recognier
        cell.textLabel!.text = model.tagAtIndex(index: indexPath.row)

        // set up long press guesture recognizer
        let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
            target: self, action: Selector(("tableViewCellLongPressed:")))
        longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)

        return cell
    }

    //callback that return whether a cell is editable
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true // all cells are editable
    }

    // callback that deletes a row from the UITableView
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            model.deleteurlSearchAtIndex(index: indexPath.row)

            // remove UITableView row
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
    // callback that returns whether cells can be moved
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

    // callback that reorders keys when user moves them in the table
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                            to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        // tell model to reorder tags based on UITableView order
        model.moveTagAtIndex(oldIndex: sourceIndexPath.row,
                             toDestinationIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you will need the DetailViewController.swift or the Model.swift files but if you do I can provide them.

Comment: Check for your button in the storyboard and see if the addButtonPressed link exists, with that exact name.

Comment: Do a search on "unrecognized selector". This is _very_ common and has been well covered here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of all the other "unrecognized selector" questions.

Comment: See for example my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40964344/341994 This is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this expression:

```
Selector(("addButtonPressed:"))
```

Replace it with:

```
#selector(addButtonPressed)
```

Comment: You didn't perform the substitution precisely as I said (or as you claimed). If you had done what I said, the line would now read `let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonPressed))`. It evidently doesn't.

Comment: When I changed the code to this, the simulator will not load. It just stops and takes me to this: ->  0x10af51dcc <+380>:  movq   -0x88(%rbp), %rdi and says Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1. It does not give me any other errors or say anything about terminating like before.

Comment: That is because you created a breakpoint and now we are pausing at it. It has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Sorry, I am brand new at this. Thank you for pointing that out. Took me a bit to figure out what those were. That seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean the build folder and restart Xcode