# Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I sublcassed in Swift 3 a `UIButton` subclass that is written in Objective-C.

When I try to add a target, it fails with an error code:

```
class ActionButton: JTImageButton {

    func action() {

    }

    func configure()) {
        // ...
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.action()), for: .touchUpInside)
        // error: 
        // Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `action` method conflicts with the `action(for:, forKey:)` method of `UIView`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

All you have to do is mark the func as `@objc` and there's no need for the `self` reference or the parenthesis

```
class ActionButton: JTImageButton {

    @objc func btnAction() {

    }

    func configure() {
        // ...
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        // error: 
        // Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

    }
}
```

You can even make it `private` if you want

Comment: Thanks, but it says `Ambiguous use of 'action'` when I implemented your approach? Edit: Renaming `action()` to `action2()` helped.

Comment: Weird. I renamed the method to be `btnAction` and it doesn't give me that error. Maybe something to do with the function name, `action`? I've updated my answer to show what I mean

Comment: You don't need the `@objc` because the class already inherits from NSObject.

Comment: True. Since it's a public method on an `NSObject` there's no need for the `@objc`. If the func were to be made `private` it would be needed

Answer (score 80):

The problem is that in `#selector(self.action())`, `self.action()` is a *method call*. You don't want to *call* the method; you want to *name* the method. Say `#selector(action)` instead: lose the parentheses, plus there's no need for the `self`.

Comment: In addition, it  conflicts with the `action(for:, forKey:)` method of `UIView`. `#selector(action)` will give an "ambiguous use"  and your Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax applies.

Comment: so `func action() {

    }` has to be repalced with some other name as @matt said otherwise you  will end up with `Ambiguous use of action() ` error.

Comment: Agreed. I'll point that out in my answer. I was answering the intent of the question, not the technicals. I shouldn't do that!

Comment: What if function with more than one Argument?

Comment: What if it does?

Comment: What if the named func has more than one Argument... how and where to fill those Arguments??

Comment: @Let.Simoo There are no arguments in a `#selector` expression. You are _describing_ the method, not calling it.

Answer (score 14):

Adding `@objc` keyword in the front the method that is perfect, but I still got this error. 
Finally, I found out the solution as follows
[image]

There is a pair of superfluous parentheses behind the method as picture shown above. What I should do is that remove it and it worked well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question's needs. Also, please don't repost answers.

Comment: This is the answer I came across, and someone may encounter too. And I solved it by removing the parenthesis. Why you downvoted my answer?   It's REAL answer! @paper1111

Answer (score 2):

Added from comments on another answer: **func action()** is not just a poor choice for a function name and action, it fails to build. (You can use it as an input function parameter though, which I do for clarity when passing in target/action to an init() that sets these things.) I'm replacing this with **MyAction()** for clarity.

---

Try this:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

The said, a much better design is to move the MyAction() function to the button superview, as that makes things more aligned with basic MVC design:

Superview:

```
let myButton = ActionButton()
// include other button setup here
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyAction), for: .touchUpInside

func action(_ sender: ActionButton) {
    // code against button tap here
}
```

Alternative coding for this, keeping the "action()" method in the view controller but moving **only** the "addTarget" into the button:

```
self.addTarget(superview?, action(superview?.MyAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Why am I asking you to consider moving the "MyAction()" method to the superview? Twofold:

- It controls not only the button, but all other subviews in it's view and they commonly interact with each other via the view controller.
- It makes the button much more reusable in other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying `self.action()`, use `ActionButton.action()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind adding an extra function, you could nest the function.

```
self.addTarget(self, action: myAction, for: UIControlledEvent)

myAction(){
    @obj.methodYouWantToCall(//parameters//)
}
```