# Passing a function with overloads won't compile

Tags: swift, functional-programming, overloading

I'm trying to pass a function to a closure or another function, but there are overloads which prevent compilation due to ambiguity. I'm wondering if this can actually be done?

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve -

```
let closure: (UILabel, String, ((CGFloat) -> (UIFont))) -> () = { (label, text, createFont) in
    label.text = text
    label.font = createFont(20)
}

let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont  // won't compile - Ambiguous use of 'systemFont'
let boldSystemFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont // this is fine, no overloads

closure(myLabel, "Some text", systemFont)
closure(myOtherLabel, "More text", boldSystemFont)
```

Is there a way to specify which overload I want? No amount of searching on SO or Google has been able to answer this for me.

Comment: "Is there a way to specify which overload I want? No amount of searching on SO or Google has been able to answer this for me." Really? So what's this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35658335/341994

Comment: That question specifically asks about #selector, so it never appeared in my search results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "ambiguous use of" compile error with Swift #selector syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean:

```
    let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:)
```

Comment: Yup - this is the answer, thanks. Makes me feel a bit daft, pretty straight forward in the end...