# In Swift, how can you test if an object implements an optional protocol method which differs by signature without actually calling that method?

Tags: swift, protocols, option-type, optional-arguments

Using Swift, is it possible to test if an object implements an optional protocol method without actually calling that method?  This works except for cases where the optional methods differ only by their signature.

Consider this code...

```
@objc public protocol TestDelegate : AnyObject {
    @objc optional func testx()
    @objc optional func test(with string:String)
    @objc optional func test(with2 int:Int)
}

let delegate:TestDelegate? = nil

if let _ = delegate?.test(with:) {
    print("supports 'test(with:)'")
}

if let _ = delegate?.testx {
    print("supports 'testx'")
}
```

If you paste the above in a playground, it works as expected.

However, if you change `testx` to `test`, it no longer works.

Likewise, if you change `test(with2)` to `test(with)` then that won't work either.

Is there any way to test for those methods that only differ by signature?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/35658334/2976878 – you can explicitly coerce to disambiguate the overload you want e.g `delegate?.test as (() -> Void)?`.

Comment: Funny.  I tried that (and several variations) and couldn't get it to work.  Lemme try again.

Comment: Can you provide more context as to what you're trying to solve with this? It seems like an XY problem.

Comment: Nothing to 'solve' per se.  Just learning more about the language.  The above was just cut/copied from a playground I was messing around in.

Comment: @Hamish, I can't seem to get your answer to work with the 2nd case above (where the argument name is the same, but the type is different.) Is that possible?

Comment: @MarqueIV Hmm, works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/27bc3abc964aadaefe7b1c7add3958a8

Comment: Aaah! I see what I was doing wrong. I needed the trailing '?' because it's treated as an (implicitly-unwrapped) optional.  Adding the '?' at the end of the cast worked.

Comment: @Hamish, mind putting that as an answer (hopefully copying over your code) so I can close this out?

Comment: @MarqueIV Sure, will do when I get a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also shown in [How do I resolve "ambiguous use of" compile error with Swift #selector syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35658334/2976878), you can explicitly coerce a function reference to its expected type in order to resolve such ambiguities.

The only difference being, as such function references are to `@optional` protocol requirements done through optional chaining, you need to coerce to the optional type of the function. From there, you can do a comparison with `nil` in order to determine if both the delegate is non-nil, and it implements the given requirement.

For example:

```
import Foundation

@objc public protocol TestDelegate : AnyObject {
  @objc optional func test()

  // Need to ensure the requirements have different selectors.
  @objc(testWithString:) optional func test(with string: String)
  @objc(testWithInt:) optional func test(with int: Int)
}

class C : TestDelegate {
  func test() {}
  func test(with someString: String) {}
  func test(with someInt: Int) {}
}

var delegate: TestDelegate? = C()

if delegate?.test as (() -> Void)? != nil {
  print("supports 'test'")
}

if delegate?.test(with:) as ((String) -> Void)? != nil {
  print("supports 'test w/ String'")
}

if delegate?.test(with:) as ((Int) -> Void)? != nil {
  print("supports 'test w/ Int'")
}

// supports 'test'
// supports 'test w/ String'
// supports 'test w/ Int'
```

Note that I've given the `test(with:)` requirements unique selectors in order to ensure they don't conflict (this doesn't affect the disambiguation, only allowing class `C` to conform to `TestDelegate`).

Comment: Accepted! :) This raises a new question though.  Can you disambiguate between `func test(a: String)` and `func test(b: String)`?  Technically they are two different signatures, but if you can only test on the type, I'm not sure you can check without resorting to another form of interrogation.

Answer (score 4):

Hey MarqueIV for checking the optional you can use inbuilt function

**func responds(to aSelector: Selector!) -> Bool**

Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver implements or inherits a method that can respond to a specified message.

The application is responsible for determining whether a false response should be considered an error.

You cannot test whether an object inherits a method from its superclass by sending responds(to:) to the object using the super keyword.

This method will still be testing the object as a whole, not just the superclass’s implementation.

Therefore, sending responds(to:) to super is equivalent to sending it to self.

Instead, you must invoke the NSObject class method instancesRespond(to:) directly on the object’s superclass, as illustrated in the following code fragment.

Listing 1

```
if( [MySuperclass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)] ) {
    // invoke the inherited method
    [super aMethod];
}
```

You cannot simply use [[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)] since this may cause the method to fail if it is invoked by a subclass.

Note that if the receiver is able to forward aSelector messages to another object, it will be able to respond to the message, albeit indirectly, even though this method returns false.
Parameters
aSelector
A selector that identifies a message.
Returns 
true if the receiver implements or inherits a method that can respond to aSelector, otherwise false.
SDKs    iOS 2.0+, macOS 10.0+, tvOS 9.0+, watchOS 2.0+

Comment: Very knowledgeable!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's Objective-C.  My question was specifically around Swift where that isn't available.

Comment: @MarqueIV this explanation is in Objective-C but the method I wrote in bold letters is in swift, plz check,  Xcode will autosuggest it.

Comment: Manually calling `responds(to:)` IMO isn't an idiomatically Swift way to check if a class instance implements an `@optional` protocol requirement. Such references return optional functions in order to model the fact that the conforming class may not have implemented them.