# A function with parameters that doesn't require its parameters at the call site?

Tags: swift

I am wondering why I am not required to provide any parameters at the call site of the function on `line 19`

[image: Code Snippet of a custom timer]

I have a strong feeling its because of the `static` keyword on the function but I still would like more clarity / insight. Thanks

Code in text form below (if it helps)

```
  import SwiftUI
  import Combine


   final class CurrentTime: ObservableObject {
    @Published var seconds: TimeInterval = CurrentTime.currentSecond(date: Date())
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
    private var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        timer.map(Self.currentSecond).assign(to: \.seconds, on: self).store(in: &store) // <-- Why am I not asked for a parameter here
    }
    
    
    private static func currentSecond(date: Date) -> TimeInterval {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
        let referenceDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: components.year!, month: components.month!, day: components.day!))!
        return Date().timeIntervalSince(referenceDate)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `map` take? How does the supplied function (by name) 'fit' this requirement?

Comment: Option clicked map... `func map<T>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Output) -> T) -> Publishers.Map<Self, T>`

Comment: Which parameter are you referring to?

Comment: @NewDev in the declaration of `currentSecond` its said that it has one parameter named `date` but I am not required to call it at the call site

Comment: You're passing the function as a reference to `map`. `map` will call it. `map` accepts a closure parameter of the type `(Output) -> T`, which in this case is inferred to be: `(Date) -> TimeInterval`, which is the same type as `currentSecond`

Comment: Read more here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID174

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL:DR** There is no "call site". You are *referring* to a function, not *calling* it.

---

Let's take a simpler case:

```
let array = [1,2,3]
func doubler(_ i:Int) -> Int { i*2 }
let array2 = array.map(doubler)
print(array2) // [2,4,6]
```

The goal is to use `map` to multiply every element of an array of Int by 2. And we did that.

Now, we *could* have done it like this:

```
let array2 = array.map {$0*2}
```

But what *is* that `{$0*2}`? It's shorthand for this:

```
let array2 = array.map { (i:Int) -> Int in
    let i2 = i*2
    return i2
}
```

In other words, the curly braces are the body of an anonymous function that takes an Int and returns an Int.

But no law says that the `map` parameter must be an *anonymous* function. It happens we already have a *real* function that takes an Int and returns an Int — `doubler`.

So instead of a function body in curly braces, we can pass the named function. How? By a *function reference*. We are not *calling* `doubler`, we are telling `map` the *name* of the function that *it* will call.

The simplest way to form a function reference is just to use the bare name of the function. It isn't the only way, but there's no problem using it here. (For more about function reference syntax, see my [How do I resolve "ambiguous use of" compile error with Swift #selector syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax.))

---

Extra for experts: my favorite use of this shorthand is:

```
let sum = array.reduce(0, +)
print(sum) // 6
```

What just happened??? The same thing: in Swift, `+` is *the name of a function.*

Answer (score 2):

`currentSecond` is a function that takes a `Date` and returns a `TimeInterval`.

[`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/timerpublisher/3329524-map) is declared like this:

```
func map<T>(_ transform: @escaping (Date) -> T) -> Publishers.Map<Timer.TimerPublisher, T>
```

Its parameter type is `(Date) -> T`. `T` is a generic parameter that can be any type of your choice.

`(Date) -> T` is the type of functions that takes a `Date` as parameter and return `T`.

That's exactly what `currentSecond` is, if you set `T` to be `TimeInterval`. This is why you can pass `Self.currentSecond`, a function, to `map`. Also note that you are not calling the function at this point. `map` decides when to call it, and how many times to call it, if ever.

You can't pass `Self.currentSecond(date: someParameter)` because that would be passing a `TimeInterval` to `map`, and `map` doesn't want that.

`static` just means that the function belongs to the class, rather than individual instances of the class. The author probably thought it made more sense this way. Syntactically though, there's nothing stopping you from removing `static`, in which case you should also remove `Self.`.