# What does array.map(CGFloat.init(_:)) do?

Tags: swift

I found this in some open source code.

I am familiar with map(), but not the `CGFloat.init(_:))` part.

The Swift code is as follows:

```
if let array = propertyListValue as? [Int], array.count == 3 || array.count == 4 {
        let floats = array.map(CGFloat.init(_:))
}
```

Not sure what to look for in docs. I know what `_ name : Type` means in a function declaration... but just confused by this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` takes one argument, a function that accepts an argument of the sequence element type and returns any type. `CGFloat.init` is the name of (technically a reference to) just such a function.

Perhaps you think of `map` as taking a "closure", and indeed you could equivalently have said

```
map { CGFloat($0) }
```

here; but that's in fact exactly the same sort of function — it's just that instead of the function's name (reference) you're supplying its body.

Comment: clearflight said that they already understand what `map` is. They are asking about the `_:` part of the statement.

Comment: So I assume that passing the signature for the parameters is similar to #selector(function(_:)) where you're saying here is my func ref, and here is how it should be called. Got it. Ty

Comment: My explanation of function reference _syntax_ (if that's in fact what's not understood) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35658335/341994